# How can I automatically check that the nuget versions in a csproj file match the versions in the packages.config file?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, csproj

We have an issue where Visual Studio sometimes fails to install/restore a nuget package correctly and with an out-of-memory error in the Package Manager console, but it's not easily visible. When this occurs the versions in the `csproj` and `packages.config` file can go out of sync with no other visible indication in Visual Studio.

I've tried to write an automatic file comparer using regexes, but sometimes the package names do not match so I still have to check everything manually.

Is there reliable way to perform this check? Or to perhaps to recreate the `packages.config` file based on what is in the `csproj` file? That way I can just check the source diffs.

Comment: No, there's no automatic tooling that I'm aware of that can do that. In case you're not aware, NuGet added a different way to reference packages, PackageReference, which eliminates this problem as something that can happen, but does not support everything that packages.config does, so sometimes it's not possible to migrate, but in the majority of cases it is. Also, Visual Studio 2022 is now 64-bit, so you should never get out of memory crashes again if you upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. However this is a legacy ASP.NET solution that we can't migrate for various reasons. Moving to VS2022 also doesn't help me fix the existing discrepancies. Do you know what the include statement in the csproj file refers to? Is it the assembly/package name?

Comment: I don't feel I understand your question, because the `Include="..."` XML attributes in the csproj have the path to a specific dll or props or targets file, so I expect it would already be obvious to you what it refers to. Basically, the csproj knows NOTHING about NuGet, so NuGet extracts the package defined in packages.config to a standard location, and then the csproj is edited as if NuGet doesn't exist, pointing to the location that NuGet extracted files to.  Does that help?  If not, please be more specific.

Comment: You are mistaken. The include attribute does not include the path. There is a hint path that is a separate attribute and is not guaranteed. But I'm guessing what you are trying to say is that it refers to the dll name without the extension.

Comment: oh, I see. The include is the assembly filename in the package, but it's only by convention that assembly name == package name. There's nothing preventing a package using different assembly names, and any package with multiple assemblies can only have one assembly at most match the package name.  You have to parse the HintPath to figure out the package name and version if you want to be certain. Don't forget that packages can have props/targets that are imported in the csproj, so it's not only Reference items that might get out of sync with the packages.config version.